# Enable hyphens in URLs for MVC 5 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

My project is multilingual and also has routing, but I need to allow hyphens in the URLs, such as: example.com/en/our-team.

In this website (http://www.bousie.co.uk/blog/allow-dashes-within-urls-using-asp-net-mvc4/) I found a solution to this, adding the following code in Global.asax :

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
{
  requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] =
      requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
  requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] =
     requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-",  "_");
  return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
}
}
```

And on RouteConfig.cs, replace this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this:

```
routes.Add(
new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new RouteValueDictionary(
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }),
     new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
     );
```

The problem is that i don't know how to do it in my code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace theme_mvc
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapLocalizeRoute("Default",

            url: "{culture}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = "[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}" });

        routes.MapRouteToLocalizeRedirect("RedirectToLocalize",

                    url: "{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
    }
    }
```

How could i adapt my code to support hyphens (-) in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The link you have posted to uses the wrong approach. Routing is a 2-way mapping, but if you only customize the MvcRouteHandler, you are only taking into account the incoming routes.

This issue comes up so often that someone has created a [hyphenated lowercase route](https://github.com/AtaS/lowercase-dashed-route) project on GitHub, which would do what you want except you need to also combine it with the route that is being called by your `MapLocalizeRoute` extension method.

But since you have not posted the code for `MapLocalizeRoute` or `MapRouteToLocalizeRedirect` I can't tell you how that is done.